# Adding objects to generic array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, iterator

I am trying to add objects with a for loop to my generic array in Java. I kind of want to implement an Iterator with the Iterable interface but I don't know how. In the following code, whenever I print it out to the console, I get the following output: "package.ArrayObjects@3343c8b3"

Code:

```
public class ArrayObjects<E> implements SomeImp<E>{

    private E[] array;

    private int maxCapacity, currentSize;

    public ArrayObjects(){
        currentSize = 0;
        maxCapacity = 100;
        array = (E[]) new Object[maxCapacity];
    }

    public void addAtEnd(E obj){
        //array.add(obj); -> Cannot invoke add(E) on the array tipe E[ ]. Do you know why?
        list[currentSize++] = obj;
    }
}
```

My for loop:

```
for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++)
   array.addAtEnd(i); 

System.out.println("Should print 1 .. 10"); 
System.out.println(list);
```

EDIT: I want to use this for loop to print, but it can only be used with an Iterable object.. (how do I do so?)

```
for(int x : list)
   System.out.print(x + " ");
```

How could I fix this? Do you know how to implement an Iterator to loop through the array as well? I would have to declare that my class also implements Iterator right?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What output were you expecting? Why?

Comment: could you see my edits? I think that it'll give you a better idea of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, we can see your edits. However, I did not ask what you are trying to achieve. I asked what output you were expecting from your code and why.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I fix this?

Read the javadoc for the `Object.toString()` method.  That's what is being used to "format" the array `list` for output.

Then look at the javadoc for the static method `Arrays.toString(Object[])`.  That's probably the simplest way to format your array to give the kind of output you are looking for.

---

> Do you know how to implement an Iterator to loop through the array as well?

This is mooted by the above ... but you can iterate over an array in a couple of simple ways:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        // iterates over the array indexes
    }

    for (e E : list) {
        // iterated over the array elements
    }
```

(This is all Java 101 stuff ... and *should* have been covered by your teacher / textbook / tutorial)

---

> I would have to declare that my class also implements Iterator right?

That is another approach ... sort of.

Actually, you should make your class implement `Iterable` ... which means adding an `Iterator<E> iterator()` method, and implementing it to return an iterator object with the required semantics.  A quick-and-dirty approach would be to use `Arrays.asList` to wrap the array in  a `List` and then return an iterator for the `List`.

If your class implemented `Iterator` directly, you would only be able to iterate the elements once ... 'cos the `Iterator` API provides no way to start again.

The other problem is that your existing code seems to be updating a `list` object that is not a member of the `ArrayObjects` class.  This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  But assuming it is intentional, then your `ArrayObjects` is a leaky abstraction, and the use of `Iterable` is highly questionable.

Comment: do you know how can I use an Iterator regarding my array?

Comment: Regarding your last update: yes exactly!!! Thats what I wanted to do!! use the Iterator! first off I have to import it right? I read the documentation about Iterable but I can't find examples with generic arrays anywhere. Do you happen to know how to do this or where can I find more info about this? Thank you so much!

Comment: 1)  *"I have to import it right?"* - Of course! 2) *"Do you happen to know how to do this ..."* - yes :-)  3) http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/implementing-iterable.html